# Need to inject some value to an outgoing SOAP response in CXF

Tags: jakarta-ee, cxf, cxf-client

I am using CXF, my question is two folds:

1) How can I generate a custom soap header for an outgoing response?

2) How can I inject some value from the implementation function?

Answer (score 0):

For the question 1)

`Client proxy = ClientProxy.getClient(yourClient);
List<Header> headersList = new ArrayList<Header>();
Header header = new Header(new QName("uri:my.uri", "mysoapheader"), "Header Content", new JAXBDataBinding(String.class));
headersList.add(header);
proxy.getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headersList);`

For question 2), I don't understand what you want to do.